# Typescript Project Documenting and UML diagrams

Tags: class, typescript, uml

I have a pretty decent Typescript project. There are several classes , interfaces and it has scaled a fair bit of amount.

I wanted to know how can I document my project as well as how can I draw Class Diagrams for typescript project I have.

What else can I do so junior developers understand it ? What else diagrams will be good for the project.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would suggest commenting your TypeScript code using the JSDoc convention, compile your TS code without stripping off comments (`removeComments` to `false` in *tsconfig.json*), and use a documentation generator on the JS files.

Based on that, you could maybe find a tool to generate UML diagram from JSDoc : [JSDoc UML Diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664842/jsdoc-uml-diagram)