# How to generate TypeScript UML class diagrams?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, uml

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to create Web Apps and I just start using `TypeScript`.

As my project gets bigger, I'm wondering if there's a way to get UML diagram of `TypeScript` code using Visual Studio, extensions or any other free tool.

Comment: Keep in mind that some solutions such as TsUML will upload your code without telling you.

Answer (score 36):

I am using a VSC extension named classdiagram-ts from AlexShen that does a very nice job, it can be used for creating a diagram for a file or a folder and also lets you reposition and navigate to fields, hide members and other cool options.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlexShen.classdiagram-ts&ssr=false#overview

Comment: Layout with this tool does not seem sophisticated, compared to GraphViz (PlantUML). It just puts classes horizontally. You'll have to spend time moving them around to see everything.

Comment: Be aware this is not open source: "It's a personal close source project, no public repo."

Answer (score 10):

You can try [tplant](https://github.com/bafolts/tplant). Here's an example for the typescript classes at https://github.com/pascalerni/abap2famix/tree/master/src

[image: tplant with Compositions option turned on]

Another alternative, which I currently use but requires VSCode, is: [vscode-ts-uml](https://github.com/myxvisual/vscode-ts-uml)

Comment: tplant gave me great results (hard to do better than PlantUML for layouts).

Comment: be careful, this tool uses a remote server

Answer (score 6):

I would advise against doing anything with TsUML. You install it as a regular NPM package, but then it uses some sketchy online service. It seems dangerous to use Tsuml for proprietary projects.

Comment: There is an offline version of it: https://github.com/demike/TsUML2

Comment: Has anyone verified that it does not contact a server? (other than the authors)

Answer (score 4):

for  Visual Studio :
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzadRatzki.TypeScriptDiagram#overview

for vscode :
https://github.com/remojansen/TsUML

or

I would suggest commenting your TypeScript code using the JSDoc convention, compile your TS code without stripping off comments (removeComments to false in tsconfig.json), and use a documentation generator on the JS files.

Based on that, you could maybe find a tool to generate UML diagram from JSDoc : [JSDoc UML Diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664842/jsdoc-uml-diagram)

Comment: TsUML upload your code on their server without telling you.

Answer (score 1):

Using [TsUML](https://github.com/remojansen/TsUML):

```
npm install -g tsuml
# Note: this posts data to https://yuml.me!!
tsuml --glob ./src/**/*.ts
```

Comment: TsUML upload your code on their server without telling you.

Comment: Did not work. I posted my problem at a similar issue. https://github.com/remojansen/TsUML/issues/11#issuecomment-612934131

Answer (score 1):

There is now an open-source package called TsUML2 that, in their words:

> works offline, so no third party servers are involved.

https://github.com/demike/TsUML2

Answer (score 0):

I found a very useful site to convert TS to UML diagram

https://tsuml-demo.firebaseapp.com/

copy following code and paste it under Typescript Tab

```
export class BaseDTO {
  created: number;
  createdBy: string;
  updated: number;
  updatedBy: string;
}

export class PaymentDTO extends BaseDTO {
  paymentId: number;
  paymentReference: string;
  amount: string;
  paymentPayee: { name: string }
}
```

**Example:**

[image]